# Creating an OpenLayers 5 MultiPolygon feature from a turf.js MultiPolygon

Tags: openlayers-5, turfjs

In OpenLayers 5.3.0, I've created a MultiPolygon using the 'difference' tool in turf.js. The turf.js MultiPolygon looks fine when I examine the JSON, but when I try to use that to create a feature in OpenLayers, I get "Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function".

I've tried many combinations of JSON.stringify, JSON.parse, GeoJSON.readFeatures, .getCoordinates()... I tried adding the turf.js MultiPolygon as a feature directly via `source.addFeature(multiPolygonGeometry)`, but then I get 'Uncaught TypeError: e.getId is not a function'. I also tried `source.addFeatures(multiPolygonGeometry)` (note the plural 'addFeatures'), and that didn't give me any errors, but also didn't appear to add anything to the source.

Relevant lines in my code are as follows:

```
multiPolygonGeometry = turf.difference(largeArea,maskAreas);
multiPolygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: multiPolygonGeometry,
  id: 'multiPolygonFeature1'
});
```

multiPolygonGeometry looks like this in the console:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            140.9716711384525,
            -36.97645228850101
          ],
          [
            140.97418321565786,
            -36.97679331852701
          ],
          [
            140.9741163253784,
            -36.97713531664132
          ],
          [
            140.9740304946899,
            -36.97903805606076
          ],
          [
            140.97437381744382,
            -36.98025509866784
          ],
          [
            140.97594864874696,
            -36.98127512642501
          ],
          [
            140.9714880598484,
            -36.9804459718428
          ],
          [
            140.9714500775476,
            -36.97642733756345
          ],
          [
            140.9716711384525,
            -36.97645228850101
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          [
            140.97455248763328,
            -36.97684309230892
          ],
          [
            140.97751071844857,
            -36.97723786980259
          ],
          [
            140.97749308140382,
            -36.977304276099005
          ],
          [
            140.97715289421623,
            -36.97770848336402
          ],
          [
            140.97661807025068,
            -36.97969050789806
          ],
          [
            140.97628355026242,
            -36.97958658471583
          ],
          [
            140.97634792327878,
            -36.97900377288852
          ],
          [
            140.9764981269836,
            -36.97866094031662
          ],
          [
            140.97510337829587,
            -36.97727245260485
          ],
          [
            140.97455248763328,
            -36.97684309230892
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          [
            140.97628420893903,
            -36.98092777726751
          ],
          [
            140.97617893060388,
            -36.98131793226549
          ],
          [
            140.97596635572492,
            -36.98127841787872
          ],
          [
            140.97628420893903,
            -36.98092777726751
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "ol_lm": {
    "change": []
  }
}
```

And then I get this message:

```
events.js:174 Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function
    at v (events.js:174)
    at e.handleGeometryChanged_ (Feature.js:210)
    at e (events.js:41)
    at e.dispatchEvent (Target.js:101)
    at e.notify (Object.js:151)
    at e.set (Object.js:170)
    at e.setProperties (Object.js:186)
    at new e (Feature.js:108)
    at getPolygon (maskedPolygon.js:319) <-- this is the second line in my code sample above
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't seem to crack this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turf works with GeoJSON features so your "multiPolygonGeometry" is a GeoJSON feature  which can be parsed by OpenLayers then given an Id:

```
multiPolygonFeature = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(multiPolygonGeometry);
multiPolygonFeature.setId('multiPolygonFeature1');
```

Comment: Brilliant. I was sure I'd tried that already, but apparently not - works like a charm. I had to add `multiPolygonFeature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');` to put the feature where it was meant to be (and not in the Gulf of Guinea), but you solved the harder part for me. Thanks a lot.